# Should i be calling Entity Framework SaveChanges once or individually after each change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, domain-driven-design

I have an ASP.NET MVC Controller called Party.  On the CreateParty view the user can enter Party information and choose a number of Party Users.

When save is clicked i pass the data from the controller to a service class called PartyService which is responsible for saving the details (i am trying to use DDD principles).

```
public class PartyService
{
   public void SaveParty(PartyDTO party, List<UserDTO> users)
   {
       int pId = SaveSingleParty(party);

       foreach (UserDTO u in users)
       {
           SaveSinglePartyUser(u, pId);
       }

   }

   private int SaveSingleParty(PartyDTO party)
   {
       //open new context
       //add to Party repository
       //call save changes
       //close context
   }

   private void SaveSinglePartyUser(UserDTO user, int partyId)
   {
       //open new context
       //add to Party repository
       //call save changes
       //close context
   }
}
```

My concern with this code is that a new context is created for saving a party and then for each party user.  I could just change the SaveParty method so i do everything in there (open 1 context and do all changes before calling SaveChanges once).

What benefit do i get from either approach?  What i would point out is there will probably be only 1 place in the application where the user can create parties and party users.

I am new to the whole architecture thing so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into DDD Aggregates ? What is the aggregate in your example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a single `DbContext` per ASP.NET request.

In your case, it makes sense that the `SaveParty` creates an instance of the context and make the `SaveSingleParty` and `SaveSinglePartyUser` use that instance to create and insert the entities, and then only `SaveParty` would call `SaveChanges`.

The advantage is that a single `SaveChanges` call will send a single SQL query to the database instead of many SQL queries. Also, `SaveChanges` will run under a [single transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). This means that all the data will be either saved or not saved. That is, you cannot have a scenario where some of the users are saved and some are not.

Answer (score 0):

Only one context would be required

```
1. to be opened
2. save related objects in a transaction 
3. and gets closed
```

also since party and partyUsers objects are related (1 to many relation) so

```
1. you need to add user objects directly in party's user collection 
2. and add party object (which contains users collection) to context 
3. and call context.SaveChanges();
```